# Decreasing space between sections in llncs

Tags: spacing, sectioning, lncs

I want to squeeze the space for sections, subsections, and subsubsections on a llncs document. The following can only squeeze subsubsections. How could I squeeze sections and subsections?

```
   \documentclass{llncs}% http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0
    \begin{document}
    \section{A section}
    Some text
    \subsection{A subsection}
    Some text
    \subsubsection{A subsubsection}
    Some text
    \subsubsection{Another subsubsection}
    Some text

    \bigskip

    % Put the block below in your LaTeX preamble
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                           {-8\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -4\p@}% Formerly -18\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -4\p@
                           {-0.5em \@plus -0.22em \@minus -0.1em}%
                           {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath}}
    \makeatother

    \section{A section}
    Some text
    \subsection{A subsection}
    Some text
    \subsubsection{A subsubsection}
    Some text
    \subsubsection{Another subsubsection}
    Some text
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to do to same `\renewcommand{\subsection}` and `\renecommand{section}` with `\@startsection` and replacing `subsubsection` there with `subsection` and `section` respectively? You've to replace the individual spacings of course too and the first figure too.

Comment: If you plan to use the documentclass for something official (e.g., conference/journal/book submission) then it is probably not allowed to change spacing like this.

Comment: I deleted my post since I find it's no good idea to screw up the spacings etc.

Answer (score 3):

I have found an answer, just using the following code, can do it

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
                       {-8\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -4\p@}%
                       {6\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 4\p@}%
                       {\normalfont\large\bfseries\boldmath
                        \rightskip=\z@ \@plus 8em\pretolerance=10000 }}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                       {-8\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -4\p@}%
                       {6\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 4\p@}%
                       {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath
                        \rightskip=\z@ \@plus 8em\pretolerance=10000 }}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                       {-4\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -4\p@}%
                       {-1.5em \@plus -0.22em \@minus -0.1em}%
                       {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This is basically the same I had in my (deleted) answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I copyed from the original one from llncs, and then just changed the line spacing number